# grunt.js: can multiple npm task run at the same time?

Tags: gruntjs

I want use `uglify` to minify js file, and want use `concat` to concat the several js file,

So, I have to create a temporary folder to store the fisrt step minify file ?

and then I concat the minified file together?

Is it possible do this without temp folder, do the two job at the same time? or using the computer memory?

Comment: you could `concat` your js files into one and then `uglify` that "in place"

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading the docs of those tasks. The first example in the uglify task docs shows [how you can concat files](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#basic-compression) and then uglify:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    target: {
      files: {
        'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```